# Importing a crate into a const block

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a procedural macro that implements a `#[derive()]` trait for a struct. In the generated implementation code I need to use [`AnyMap`](https://crates.io/crates/anymap).

To avoid multi crate imports, and based on what I read in some other crate's code (namely Serde) I put my generated code into a `const _IMPL_xxx_FOR_xxx : () = { /* generated code */ };` block but it fails to compile.

I was able to replicate my issue with the following code

```
const BLOCK_1: () = {
    extern crate anymap;
    use anymap::AnyMap;
};

const BLOCK_2: () = {
    extern crate anymap;
    use anymap::AnyMap;
};

fn main() {
    println!("foo");
}
```

The compile error I'm getting is the following:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `anymap::AnyMap`
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     use anymap::AnyMap;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Maybe a missing `extern crate anymap;`?

error[E0432]: unresolved import `anymap::AnyMap`
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |     use anymap::AnyMap;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Maybe a missing `extern crate anymap;`?
```

Is it an issue specific to [`AnyMap`](https://crates.io/crates/anymap)? Would you know of any way to fix this (including maybe a different approach to generating procedural macro code if the pattern I'm using is not recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate this on the playground using simply

```
const A: () = {
    extern crate core;
    use core::option::Option;
};

fn main() {}
```

However, it appears only the `use` statement is broken, and I can still use items from core, but I have to name them explicitly each time:

```
const A: () = {
    extern crate core;
    do_stuff!(core::option::Option)
};
```

The reason is that `use` statements typically assume a path relative to the root, and there is no way to explicitly name the block you are in (`self` refers to the current module unfortunately).

Here's a better workaround - as I said before, Rust uses `self` to refer to the current module, so you can just put a module in your code block and then have the `use` statements reference `self`.

In your case it would be:

```
const BLOCK_1: () = {
    mod inner {
        extern crate anymap;
        use self::anymap::AnyMap;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for these elements @Djzin. So if use is indeed broken what is then the best way to manage imports when using procedural macros ?

Comment: One thing you can do is put your code into a module, and then you can import using `use self::anymap::Anymap`. You can still put the module inside the const delaration

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

On the specific issue of making this work for procedural macro, a suggested solution was to reexport the needed crate as part of the crate containing the derive macro (or the one containing the class I'm trying to export) using something like `pub extern crate anymap` and then `use <my_crate>::anymap::AnyMap;`